# iOS7 Audio Player Controls

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-controls, avaudioplayer

Does Apple provide us with some audio controls like their standard ones we see in Control Center and the native Music app? Something we can add as a subview?

Or do we have to create our own?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not. You have to create all of these controls on your own.

They do however offer several frameworks that are useful when it comes to making music playing applications. Once you create your own buttons, you can hook them up to the music API of your choice.

If you're looking to control the device's built in iPod, you'll want the [Media Player Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html), but if you're looking to create something more your own, you probably want [AVFoudation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Comment: Alright, thanks. Yes, I've already coded AVFoundation to read from the user's library - all I need are some controls now.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Simple steps:

Step 1: `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`

Step 2: Set delegate in **.h** file UIViewController<`MPMediaPlayback`>

Step 3: Write this code on **.m** file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileLocation];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
}

-(void)endSeeking
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

-(void)stop
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: This would be good if I wanted video, however I only need audio at the moment

Comment: You can play either audio/video. Am using this code in my app. Its works fine.

Comment: If need audio separately try this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/259/audio-tutorial-for-ios-playing-audio-programatically